# How do I remove non-uniform spacing between my table elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

I am trying to make a paint website and for showing the colour palette, I use an HTML table of buttons that looks something like the following:
[image]

As you can see, the first three elements of both the rows are not uniformly spaced as the other elements in that row. To see why this problem must be occurring, I also used `inspect` but I couldn't figure it out from there too because that gap wasn't being shown in the margin, border or padding of the buttons.

[image]

I can't understand this gap mainly because I have used uniform spacing and sizes for all the elements(You can see in the code snippet below). How do I correct this?

```css
html {
    min-width: 1500px;
    position: relative;
    }

#toolset {
    width     : 100px;
    height    : 340px;
    position  : absolute;
    left      : 0px;
    top       : 50px; 
    background: #35d128;
}

#paint {
    position  : absolute;
    left      : 130px;
    top       : 50px;
}

#colorset {
    position  : absolute;
    left      : 0px;
    top       : 450px;
    width     : 300px;
}

#colorset td {
    width     : 18px;
    height    : 20px;
}
 
#title {
    position  : absolute;
    left      : 500px;
}

#penciltool {
    background: #358128; 
    color     : #f3f3f3;
    width     : 80px;
    height    : 25px;
    border    : 1px solid #33842a;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 15px 15px 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 15px 15px 0;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, .75) 0 2px 6px;
}

#linetool {
    background: #358128; 
    color     : #f3f3f3;
    width     : 80px;
    height    : 25px;
    border    : 1px solid #33842a;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 15px 15px 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 15px 15px 0;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, .75) 0 2px 6px;
}

#rectangletool {
    background: #358128; 
    color     : #f3f3f3;
    width     : 80px;
    height    : 25px;
    border    : 1px solid #33842a;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 15px 15px 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 15px 15px 0;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, .75) 0 2px 6px;
}

#circletool {
    background: #358128; 
    color     : #f3f3f3;
    width     : 80px;
    height    : 25px;
    border    : 1px solid #33842a;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 15px 15px 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 15px 15px 0;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, .75) 0 2px 6px;
}

#erasertool {
    background: #358128; 
    color     : #f3f3f3;
    width     : 80px;
    height    : 25px;
    border    : 1px solid #33842a;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 15px 15px 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 15px 15px 0;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, .75) 0 2px 6px;
}

#resettool {
    background: #358128; 
    color     : #f3f3f3;
    width     : 80px;
    height    : 25px;
    border    : 1px solid #33842a;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 15px 15px 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 15px 15px 0;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, .75) 0 2px 6px;
}
```

```html
<fieldset id="colorset" style="margin-top: 1.8%;">

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><button style="height: 18px; width: 80px;" onclick="fill()">Fill</button>
                <td><button style="background-color: #000000; height: 15px; width: 15px;" onclick="color('#000000')"></button>
                <td><button style="background-color: #B0171F; height: 15px; width: 15px;" onclick="color('#B0171F')"></button>
                <td><button style="background-color: #DA70D6; height: 15px; width: 15px;" onclick="color('#DA70D6')"></button>
                <td><button style="background-color: #8A2BE2; height: 15px; width: 15px;" onclick="color('#8A2BE2')"></button>
                <td><button style="background-color: #0000FF; height: 15px; width: 15px;" onclick="color('#0000FF')"></button>
                <td><button style="background-color: #4876FF; height: 15px; width: 15px;" onclick="color('#4876FF')"></button>
                <td><button style="background-color: #CAE1FF; height: 15px; width: 15px;" onclick="color('#CAE1FF')"></button>
                <td><button style="background-color: #6E7B8B; height: 15px; width: 15px;" onclick="color('#6E7B8B')"></button>
                <td><button style="background-color: #00C78C; height: 15px; width: 15px;" onclick="color('#00C78C')"></button>
                <td><button style="background-color: #00FA9A; height: 15px; width: 15px;" onclick="color('#00FA9A')"></button>
                <td><button style="background-color: #00FF7F; height: 15px; width: 15px;" onclick="color('#00FF7F')"></button>
                <td><button style="background-color: #00C957; height: 15px; width: 15px;" onclick="color('#00C957')"></button>
                <td><button style="background-color: #FFFF00; height: 15px; width: 15px;" onclick="color('#FFFF00')"></button>
                <td><button style="background-color: #CDCD00; height: 15px; width: 15px;" onclick="color('#CDCD00')"></button>
                <td><button style="background-color: #FFF68F; height: 15px; width: 15px;" onclick="color('#FFF68F')"></button>
                <td><button style="background-color: #FFFACD; height: 15px; width: 15px;" onclick="color('#FFFACD')"></button>
                <td><button style="background-color: #FFEC8B; height: 15px; width: 15px;" onclick="color('#FFEC8B')"></button>
                <td><button style="background-color: #FFD700; height: 15px; width: 15px;" onclick="color('#FFD700')"></button>
                <td><button style="background-color: #F5DEB3; height: 15px; width: 15px;" onclick="color('#F5DEB3')"></button>
                <td><button style="background-color: #FFE4B5; height: 15px; width: 15px;" onclick="color('#FFE4B5')"></button>
                <td><button style="background-color: #EECFA1; height: 15px; width: 15px;" onclick="color('#EECFA1')"></button>
                <td><button style="background-color: #FF9912; height: 15px; width: 15px;" onclick="color('#FF9912')"></button>
                <td><button style="background-color: #8E388E; height: 15px; width: 15px;" onclick="color('#8E388E')"></button>
                <td><button style="background-color: #7171C6; height: 15px; width: 15px;" onclick="color('#7171C6')"></button>
                <td><button style="background-color: #7D9EC0; height: 15px; width: 15px;" onclick="color('#7D9EC0')"></button>
                <td><button style="background-color: #388E8E; height: 15px; width: 15px;" onclick="color('#388E8E')"></button>
                
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
                <td><button style="height: 18px; width: 80px" onclick="outline()">Outline</button>
                <td><button style="background-color: #71C671; height: 15px; width: 15px;" onclick="color('#71C671')"></button>
                <td><button style="background-color: #8E8E38; height: 15px; width: 15px;" onclick="color('#8E8E38')"></button>
                <td><button style="background-color: #C5C1AA; height: 15px; width: 15px;" onclick="color('#C5C1AA')"></button>
                <td><button style="background-color: #C67171; height: 15px; width: 15px;" onclick="color('#C67171')"></button>
                <td><button style="background-color: #555555; height: 15px; width: 15px;" onclick="color('#555555')"></button>
                <td><button style="background-color: #848484; height: 15px; width: 15px;" onclick="color('#848484')"></button>
                <td><button style="background-color: #F4F4F4; height: 15px; width: 15px;" onclick="color('#F4F4F4')"></button>
                <td><button style="background-color: #EE0000; height: 15px; width: 15px;" onclick="color('#EE0000')"></button>
                <td><button style="background-color: #FF4040; height: 15px; width: 15px;" onclick="color('#FF4040')"></button>
                <td><button style="background-color: #EE6363; height: 15px; width: 15px;" onclick="color('#EE6363')"></button>
                <td><button style="background-color: #FFC1C1; height: 15px; width: 15px;" onclick="color('#FFC1C1')"></button>
                <td><button style="background-color: #FF7256; height: 15px; width: 15px;" onclick="color('#FF7256')"></button>
                <td><button style="background-color: #FF4500; height: 15px; width: 15px;" onclick="color('#FF4500')"></button>
                <td><button style="background-color: #F4A460; height: 15px; width: 15px;" onclick="color('#F4A460')"></button>
                <td><button style="background-color: #FF8000; height: 15px; width: 15px;" onclick="color('FF8000')"></button>
                <td><button style="background-color: #FFD700; height: 15px; width: 15px;" onclick="color('#FFD700')"></button>
                <td><button style="background-color: #8B864E; height: 15px; width: 15px;" onclick="color('#8B864E')"></button>
                <td><button style="background-color: #9ACD32; height: 15px; width: 15px;" onclick="color('#9ACD32')"></button>
                <td><button style="background-color: #66CD00; height: 15px; width: 15px;" onclick="color('#66CD00')"></button>
                <td><button style="background-color: #BDFCC9; height: 15px; width: 15px;" onclick="color('#BDFCC9')"></button>
                <td><button style="background-color: #76EEC6; height: 15px; width: 15px;" onclick="color('#76EEC6')"></button>
                <td><button style="background-color: #40E0D0; height: 15px; width: 15px;" onclick="color('#40E0D0')"></button>
                <td><button style="background-color: #9B30FF; height: 15px; width: 15px;" onclick="color('#9B30FF')"></button>
                <td><button style="background-color: #EE82EE; height: 15px; width: 15px;" onclick="color('#EE82EE')"></button>
                <td><button style="background-color: #FFC0CB; height: 15px; width: 15px;" onclick="color('#FFC0CB')"></button>
                <td><button style="background-color: #7CFC00; height: 15px; width: 15px;" onclick="color('#7CFC00')"></button>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label>Line Width</label></td>
                <td><button id="pixel_plus" type="button" onclick="add_pixel()" style="width: 25px;">+</button></td>
                <td><button id="pixel_minus" type="button" onclick="reduce_pixel()" style="width: 25px;">-</button></td>
                <td><button id="undo" type="button" onclick="undo_pixel()"style="width: 75px;">Undo</button></td>

            </tr>
            </table>
            <br>
            <label>Tag</label><input id="fname" type="text"><button id="save" onclick="temp()">Add</button>
            <br>
            <br>
            </fieldset>
```

Comment: Don't use tables for layout.

Comment: Its because your undo button has a set `width` of `75px`. Each `<td>` in a table has the same width across all rows.

Comment: If you need to keep the table layout, you can add the `colspan` attribute to the wide `<td>`s so they don't affect the width of other elements in the same column.

Comment: You could eliminate 90 percent of your code by using the browser's native color picker for Fill and Outline.  Learn more:  [MDN - Color Picker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/color#try_it)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions @Paulie_D, Samball and Roberto. Taking those components of the table worked. I was following that look because of a design requirement, but I have added the Color Picker option as an extra option too, thanks.